# How should insulated plasterboard be mechanically affixed to a wall?

Tags: insulation

I am looking to internally insulate solid brick walls using a PIR-backed plasterboard product. Some of these products allow adhesive fixing but I prefer to mechanically fix directly onto the solid wall as:

- it is already decorated so the adhesive may not work well
- adhesive fixing is outside my experience
- I need to conserve space so there isn't space for battens

How should this be done and what fixings should be used? I see specialist products of many types online and it is unclear which are tried & tested.

Comment: Have you consulted the manufacturer's instructions? If they indicate gluing only, have you contacted them to see if there are any mechanical (screw, otherwise) installation methods that are applicable/appropriate? If you don't follow their instructions, you'll likely void any warranty (whatever that may be), but if you're dead set on not gluing it, then it probably doesn't matter.

Comment: DV for 'This question does not show any research effort'.

Comment: Agreed....DV for lack of any effort.

Comment: This was a painfully simple question to answer and it's _certainly_ not opinion based. Not sure how much more focus it needs. Not sure why the VtC...

Comment: Their prime method is 'glue it to the wall'. What's wrong with that? The very next link is how to fix it to battens. -1 for total lack of effort.

Comment: @Tetsujin 1)I specifically asked a question about mechanical fixing not adhesive 2)I asked about fixing to brick wall, not battens. I have reasons for that and asked a specific question. "I wouldn't do it that way" is not grounds to close.

Comment: They give 3 methods, two use glue, one to battens [which to me seems pointless for a glue-able solution]. I think you probably need to add to your question what on earth you think is wrong with the manufacturer's primary method. "I don't want to" is not really good enough.

Comment: @FreeMan I am looking to buy "seconds" and they do not tell you exactly which manufacturer it will be from. I used K118 as an example only - some of these products prohibit adhesive.

Comment: Ah, so your question is not really the question you need an answer to. If I could DV again, I would.

Comment: @Tetsujin, I never said I wanted advice for K118, I used it as an example. You have misread (seemingly deliberately to cause an argument). Google shows a wide (bewilderingly so) array of specialist fixings for this very application so it's clearly a valid question.

Comment: Honestly, it sounds like your best bet is to either A) be picky about which seconds you buy (only get brands that will allow adhesive fastening), or B) do your research _after_ purchasing `<random products>` to figure out what each manufacturer's installations instructions are and install each product according to that product's instructions. Also, if you've ever squeezed caulk through a caulk gun, you have all the experience you need to do a fine job of fastening by adhesive. If you haven't, but you've squeezed toothpaste out of a tube, you're 90% there.

Comment: You can fasten to a solid wall with regular Rawlplugs [generic 'brown plugs'] but getting your tension right to not pull the screw-heads right through the plasterboard is more trouble than it's worth. Add the cussedness of your typical rawlplug in anything other than micron-accurate holes [plus you *now* say it's already-decorated which means you need to more accurately gauge screw/plug depth] & you'll quickly find out why people just don't do it that way. Get the existing plaster off first & start with rough but bare brickwork.

Comment: It's already decorated, but you're covering it up. Scrape the wallpaper/paint/other decoration off if you're that worried about glue sticking.

Comment: Though really, unless these are unreasonably heavy or the existing surface is crumbling to pieces, construction adhesive will probably do Just Fine.

Answer (score 5):

A search for "Kingspan Kooltherm K118" led me directly to their website page for this material.

Clicking on the "Technical Information" button gave me an "Installation & Handling Guidance" section which, when expanded led to [this YouTube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MFavk3yvQ_0&t=2s) which says (eventually)

> Fix the sheets with drywall screws at 300mm centers or large headed galvanized clout nails at 150mm centers...
> Fixings should be long enough to allow a minimum penetration into the timber batten or frame

Basically, hang it just like you would drywall, with a couple of extra steps (caulking the edges) to improve the insulating properties. The video is less than 2 minutes, I'd suggest watching the whole thing.

It took me less time to find the information than it did to type up my comment asking you if you'd looked for it. :(

---

It now appears that the goal is to affix directly to the solid wall without affixing wood first.

To do, that (since screwing this stuff up seems to be acceptable), use fasteners suitable for attaching things to concrete/brick/block/stone walls. Things like Tapcons™ or mollys or toggle anchors, etc.

However, these are all designed for the head of the fastener to stand proud of the surface of the material they're fastening, so you'll then have to do something like apply a *thick* (not skim) coat of plaster or drywall joint compound to hide the heads. Frankly, sounds like it'd be easier to install the wood battens.

Comment: My question is about fixing directly to a solid wall, not to wooden battens. Your video doesn't address my question.